# How can i save a Password decryptable but securely in a database?

Tags: php, encryption, passwords, credentials, storing-data

I am currently programming a WebApp in which I need to use an API from a large company. I need to store my users' data for accessing the API somehow. How can I store my users' API keys in my database without them being used in case of a data leak?

I want the password to be linked to an account so that the user only has to enter the password once, even if they access the WebApp from different devices?

To be precise, I would need to store a username and password that can be associated with an account.

If i would encrypt the Password somehow i would really like to do it in PHP, so that everything is happening on my Servers.

I thought about encrypting the data for the API with the User Password of my WebApp but even with that i don't know how i would do that in PHP.

**Addition 02.11.2022**
The API (which is a school-timetable-app) doesn't use Keys, it uses the Login Credentials (Password and Username), with which the users even login to the application. The API is just an readout of the school-timetable-app.

Comment: Your question is unclear about whether these are API keys or username/password credentials. PHP has built-in encryption/decryption handlers (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) you can use, and storing API keys is a reasonable use of these, but storing *credentials* is almost never advisable.

Comment: use password_hash() and password_verify() they use bcrypt with is a good hashing algo, then use a sessionid cookie hash

Comment: Many APIs have the ability to associate a key with additional constraints. I'd recommend checking if you could put an IP restriction on the API keys so that even if they do leak the wouldn't be usable.

Comment: Sorry, i was unclear with that...
The API (which is a school-timetable-app) doesn't use Keys, it uses the Login Credentials (Password and Username), with which the users even login to the application. The API is just an readout of the school-timetable-app.

Comment: Do you have any way to modify the API, or is that not possible? Also, are these users logging into your application, too, and if so, is it the same credentials as the API?

Comment: Also, this answer includes additional very thorough answers that I'd encourage you to read through: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/10114/27708

Comment: The users have to login into my application, but NOT with the Same credentials they use on the API. I can't modify the API at all...

Comment: If they log into your application, you could conceivably encrypt the API credentials with a form of the user's credentials. You'd have to re-prompt for local credentials after entering the API credentials the first time, which is annoying but not the end of the world, otherwise you'd need to store the user's app password unencrypted. If a password is reset you'd also need to go through the process again. Otherwise, you can just encrypt with a shared secret on the server. Or you could encrypt at the database level. Really depends on what you are trying to secure against